# Insufficient Privileges on button click

Tags: schema, privileges

I have a class in with

> Schema.getGlobalDescribe()

getting all the object and all the information related to it. On the page load it is not giving any error I can see the filed related to all objects. But I have a command button when I click on the command button I am getting error that

> Insufficient Privileges
>   You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary

Not able to understand why this error is displayed my class is with sharing class. When I comment the schema code there is no error. May anyone here can help me out what is the issue with the

> Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

method on button click.

Comment: And what is your button doing?

Comment: just calling a method there is nothing right now in the button method

Comment: Does the User have profile access to the class?

Comment: yes it d have I have checked it. On page load it is working only the issue comes with button click.